# Получить юникод значение по ключу в Python

Tags: python-3.x

Есть строка i = '1234', как добиться значения l = '\u1234'?

Comment: нельзя склеить '\u' с чем бы то ни было.
а если сделать r'\u' + '1234', то это по сути '\\u1234', а не '\u1234'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После `\u` идет 16-е число, поэтому приведите строку `1234` к числу с основанием 16 (через `int`) и от этого числа получите символ (функция `chr`) - будет тот символ:

```
l = '\u1234'
print(l, l.encode('unicode-escape'), ord(l), hex(ord(l)))

l1 = '1234'
l2 = chr(int(l1, 16))
print(l2, l2.encode('unicode-escape'), ord(l2), hex(ord(l2)))
```

Результат:

```
ሴ b'\\u1234' 4660 0x1234
ሴ b'\\u1234' 4660 0x1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Строка `'1234'`в ASCII представлении будет иметь вид `[73, 80, 81, 82]` в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. И `[49, 50, 51, 52]` в десятеричной.

```
i = '1234'
print([int(str(j), base=16) for j in list(i.encode('utf-8'))])
print(list(i.encode('utf-8')))
```

Чтобы получить из `'1234'` `'\u1234'` просто в терминале, то использую конкатенацию с экранированием:

```
i = '1234'
print('\\u' + i)
```

Выход:

```
\u1234
```

`'\u1234'` - это ОДИН 16-битный символ UTF-8  выглядит он так: ሴ.

Ты не можешь добавить `\u` просто так из за того, что символ `'1'` в бинарном виде не соответствует ASCII коду.